# Getting the RESULT of a select query in passportjs

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I've been using django for my web development but recently switched to React and node. I'm stuck though, in trying to do some authentication with passportjs. I have these lines in my code

```
module.exports = (passport) => {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(
      { usernameField: "username" },
      async (username, password, done) => {
        try {
          const user = db
            .query("SELECT * FROM libman_customuser WHERE username=$1", [
              username,
            ])
            .then((response) => console.debug(response));
          console.debug(user);
          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: "User not found" });
          } else {
            const isMatch = await matchPassword(password, user.password);
            if (!isMatch)
              return done(null, false, { message: "Password incorrect" });
            else {
              return done(null, user);
            }
          }
        } catch (error) {
          return done(error, false);
        }
      }
    )
  );
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    // console.debug("serializing ", user);
    done(null, user);
  });
};
```

Trying to do `console.debug()` to see the result of my query does not work. I end p with the following.
What could be the reason for this?

```
Result {
  command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 0,
  oid: null,
  rows: [],
  fields: [
    Field {
      name: 'id',
      tableID: 19672,
      columnID: 1,
      dataTypeID: 23,
      dataTypeSize: 4,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'is_superuser',
      tableID: 19672,
      columnID: 2,
      dataTypeID: 16,
      dataTypeSize: 1,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'is_staff',
      tableID: 19672,
      columnID: 3,
      dataTypeID: 16,
      dataTypeSize: 1,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'is_librarian',
      tableID: 19672,
      columnID: 4,
      dataTypeID: 16,
      dataTypeSize: 1,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'is_admin',
      tableID: 19672,
      columnID: 5,
      dataTypeID: 16,
      dataTypeSize: 1,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'first_name',
      tableID: 19672,
      columnID: 6,
      dataTypeID: 1043,
      dataTypeSize: -1,
      dataTypeModifier: 259,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'last_name',
      tableID: 19672,
      columnID: 7,
      dataTypeID: 1043,
      dataTypeSize: -1,
      dataTypeModifier: 259,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'username',
      tableID: 19672,
      columnID: 8,
      dataTypeID: 1043,
      dataTypeSize: -1,
      dataTypeModifier: 259,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'email',
      tableID: 19672,
      columnID: 9,
      dataTypeID: 1043,
      dataTypeSize: -1,
      dataTypeModifier: 259,
      format: 'text'
    },...
```

Any help accorded will be highly appreciated.